# Using guards in let .. in expressions

Tags: haskell

Sometimes I write code like this

```
solveLogic :: Int -> Int -> Int
solveLogic a b =
    let 
        x = 1
        brainiac
            | a >= x     = 1
            | a == b     = 333
            | otherwise  = 5
    in
        brainiac
```

And every time I have urge to write this things without unneeded "brainiac" function,  like this:

```
solveLogic :: Int -> Int -> Int
solveLogic a b =
    let 
        x = 1
    in
        | a >= x     = 1
        | a == b     = 333
        | otherwise  = 5
```

Which code is much more "Haskellish". Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: `brainiac` is not a function, just sayin'.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a function of no arguments, given that haskell is lazy by default?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Yes, using a `where` clause:

```
solveLogic a b
        | a >= x     = 1
        | a == b     = 333
        | otherwise  = 5
    where
      x = 1
```

Answer (score 16):

When I want guards as an expression I use this somewhat ugly hack

```
case () of
_ | a >= x     -> 1
  | a == b     -> 333
  | otherwise  -> 5
```

Comment: It has to be `->` instead of `=` for case-statement guards. All but the first `_` can be left out.

Comment: A minor note for future readers: this trick can now be replaced with `if | a >= x -> 1 | a == b -> 333 | otherwise -> 5` using the `MultiWayIf` extension, which has been available since GHC 7.6.