# How do I use a guard with putStrLn?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function that will execute 2 different game modes which are defined as `tictactoe :: IO ()` and `main :: IO ()`. I'm getting a parse error on input '|'. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Could someone please explain this to me?

```
tictac :: IO()
tictac = do 
       putStrLn "Would you like to play against the computer or 
                 another player? Enter: 2 Player or Computer"
       choice <- getLine
         |choice == "Computer" = main
         |choice == "2 Player" = tictactoe
         |otherwise = putStrLn "That's not a choice!"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a limited set of places where you can use guards - they're most commonly used only in function definitions. In this situation you're probably looking for the `case` statement instead:

```
choice <- getLine
case choice of
     "Computer" -> main
     "2 Player" -> tictactoe
      _         -> putStrLn "That's not a choice!"
```

<sup>The `_` pattern matches anything, which "mops up" the leftover patterns.
 Its use here is analogous to `otherwise`, although `otherwise` is actually just syntactic sugar for `true` given that the expressions in guards are `boolean`.</sup>

It's not quite the same as guards, as guards evaluate boolean expressions while `case` does pattern matching, but it works. A more accurate dual of guards would be `if` expressions, but the `case` syntax is nicer when you can use it instead. Take a look at the [control structures](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Control_structures) page on the wiki for more examples.

---

As pointed out in the comments, it's possible to use guards in `case` expressions as well - you can see this in [the specification](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-460003.13) and in [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836222/haskell-guard-inside-case-statement). It does require at least one pattern match though, which is ugly here - you could use the ["hack" described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10371604/2193020) to do something like:

```
case () of
 _ | choice == "Computer" -> main
   | choice == "2 Player" -> tictactoe
   | otherwise            -> putStrLn "That's not a choice!"
```

But here there's no advantage to doing so.

Comment: You can use guards in other places than top level functions. `case`, defining functions in `where` and `let`, even defining values that don't take parameters in `let`.

Comment: @Potato44 Thanks for pointing out that guards can be used in `case`, I'd not seen that syntax before. I've changed the opening to make it clear that I'm talking about all functions, rather than just top-level ones. I've not been able to find an example of your very last case though, would you mind pointing me towards an example?

Comment: The question asker of the link to the ["hack"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370346/using-guards-in-let-in-expressions) you mentioned uses it in the `let` on the value `brainiac`.

Comment: The `case () of _ | choice == "Computer" -> … | choice == "2 Player" -> … | …` can be replaced with `if | choice == "Computer" -> … | choice == "2 Player" -> … | …` using the `MultiWayIf` extension, which has been available since GHC 7.6.

Comment: @JonPurdy I think that should be made a full answer because that is almost exactly what the question asker wrote besides the `if`.

Comment: @Potato44: Alright, I’ve added one. (Tried to make it different enough that it’s not redundant.)

Comment: What I don't like about guards is that they use an '=' sign after the boolean condition. It is not an equation, it is a result, an arrow.

Comment: The advantage of using guards in a case is having pattern matching drill down with booleans, and booleans again doing case. It can become as ugly as desired.

Comment: @fpmora: But it is an equation, when you’re writing a definition. It’d be inconsistent unless function definitions *without* guards used an arrow as well, like `f x y z -> impl`. A guard is just slotting `| condition` between `f x y z` and `=`, or `(Some pattern)` and `->` in `case`, without changing the surrounding syntax.

Comment: The right side of a guard expression is a result *because* a Boolean is True.
In an equation the left side becomes the right side after beta reduction.
Also, guards behave like '=' signs in recursive function definitions possible without an equal sign, such as f8 (a,b) | null b = [a] | True =  a : (f8 (splitAt 3 b)) so, I guess, is consistent. TY!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to test values like this, but the way that’s most similar to what you’ve written is to use the extension called `MultiWayIf`, available since GHC 7.6 (September 2012). Add the pragma:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf #-}
```

To the top of your source file (or use `:set -XMultiWayIf` in GHCi) and you can write the following:

```
choice <- getLine
-- Simply add the ‘if’ keyword here.
if
  | choice == "Computer" -> main
  | choice == "2 Player" -> tictactoe
  | otherwise -> putStrLn "That's not a choice!"
```

Ordinarily, guard syntax `| condition` only works in two places: in *definitions* (where a guard goes after the name & arguments, before the `=` symbol) and in `case` (where it goes after the pattern, before the `->` symbol):

```
doubleIfEven :: Int -> Int
-- Definition
doubleIfEven x
  | even x = x * 2
  --------
  | otherwise = x
  -----------

doubleIfJustEven :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
doubleIfJustEven mx
  -- Match
  = case mx of
    Just x
      | even x -> Just (x * 2)
      --------
      | otherwise -> Just x
      -----------
    Nothing -> Nothing
```

---

Here are the alternatives:

1. `case` expressions, in this case where you’re only testing for (structural) equality on strings:

   ```
   case choice of
     "Computer" -> main
     "2 Player" -> tictactoe
     _ -> putStrLn "That's not a choice!"
   ```
2. A local definition in a `where` clause or `let` binding:

   ```
   tictac :: IO ()
   tictac = do 
     putStrLn "Would you like to play against the computer or\
              \ another player? Enter: 2 Player or Computer"
     choice <- getLine
     check choice

     where
       check choice
         | choice == "Computer" = main
         | choice == "2 Player" = tictactoe
         | otherwise = putStrLn "That's not a choice!"

   ----

   tictac :: IO ()
   tictac = do 
     putStrLn "Would you like to play against the computer or\
              \ another player? Enter: 2 Player or Computer"
     let
       check choice
         | choice == "Computer" = main
         | choice == "2 Player" = tictactoe
         | otherwise = putStrLn "That's not a choice!"
     choice <- getLine
     check choice
   ```
3. Nested `if` expressions:

   ```
   if choice == "Computer" then main
     else if choice == "2 Player" then tictactoe
     else putStrLn "That's not a choice!"
   ```
4. `case` with a dummy pattern and guards (an old idiom):

   ```
   case () of
     _ | choice == "Computer" -> main
       | choice == "2 Player" -> tictactoe
       | otherwise -> putStrLn "That's not a choice!"
   ```

#1 is most common for matching; #2 is used if you need guards and either want to avoid `MultiWayIf` to support old compilers, or simply want to factor out the logic into a separate definition for readability; #3 and #4 aren’t very common or idiomatic, but there’s nothing “wrong” with them.